# Reading variable-length arrays from a FITS table using the CFITSIO library

Tags: c++, c, fits

I am having a tough time reading variable-length arrays from the entries of a FITS table, using the CFITSIO libraries (I have to use them due to another software I am developing).

Now, the FITS table I am trying to read looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the last three columns, instead of having scalar values in their cells, contain variable-length arrays.

The `CFITSIO` documentation is not very helpful with this particular case: most of the basic routine is thought to generate array by reading directly regular columns (with scalar in their cells, see section 2 of https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/fitsio/c/c_user/node46.html).
`fits_read_col` will not work with this data structure.

Now it is recommended to use the `fits_read_descript` routine when reading variable columns. The problem is that this function returns low-level information, in particular, the starting offset in the heap where the array is stored (see section 7 of https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/fitsio/c/c_user/node82.html).
So even if I get low-level information on the cell containing multiple arrays, then it is not clear how to use it to fetch the numerical values!

[CFITSIO Iterators](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/fitsio/c/c_user/node53.html) are marginally helpful, and there is no example with such complicated data structure.

Has anybody ever done this before? Is there anybody able to produce a snippet using the `CFITSIO` to read variable-length array? It would be immensely helpful.

The FITS file of which I took the screenshot can be found [here](https://github.com/open-gamma-ray-astro/joint-crab/blob/master/results/spectra/magic/rmf_obs5029747.fits).

Here a tentative snippet opening the file and examining the columns and rows, applying the suggested `fits_read_descript` function for variable-length columns. I do not know how to proceed further because I don't know how to exploit the parameters returned to fetch the actual numerical values in the table.

```
#include "fitsio.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    fitsfile *fp = 0; // pointer to fitsfile type provided in CFITSIO library
    int status = 0; // variable passed down to different CFITSIO functions 

    // open the fits file, go to the Header Data Unit 1 containing the table 
    // with variable-length arrays
    fits_open_file(&fp, "rmf_obs5029747.fits[1]", READONLY, &status);

    // read HDU type
    int hdutype;
    fits_get_hdu_type(fp, &hdutype, &status);
    std::cout << "found type " << hdutype << " HDU type." << "\n";

    // read number of rows and columns
    long nTableRows;
    int  nTableCols;
    fits_get_num_rows(fp, &nTableRows, &status);
    fits_get_num_cols(fp, &nTableCols, &status);
    std::cout << "the table has " << nTableRows << " rows" << "\n";
    std::cout << "the table has " << nTableCols << " columns" << "\n";

    // loop through the columns and consider only those with a negative typecode
    // indicating that they contain a variable-length array
    // https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/fitsio/c/c_user/node29.html
    int typecode;
    long repeat;
    long width; 
    long offset;

    for (int colnum = 0; colnum < nTableCols; ++colnum) {
        fits_get_coltype(fp, colnum+1, &typecode, &repeat, &width, &status);
        if (typecode < 1) {
            std::cout << "->column " << colnum << " contains a variable-length array" << "\n"; 
            std::cout << "->examining its rows..." << "\n";
            // loop through the rows
            for (int rownum = 0; rownum < nTableRows; ++rownum)
                fits_read_descript(fp, colnum, rownum, &repeat, &offset, &status);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @lorenz and @CraigM for your suggestions.

I actually found the solution and implemented it in the [ROOT class interfacing with the `CFITSIO` library](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTFITSHDU.html), so if someone else has the same problem can copy the solution or directly use ROOT.
The function I introduced to read a variable-length cell in ROOT is:
[TFITSHDU::GetTabVarLengthVectorCell()](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTFITSHDU.html#a0170e5ccb43f398aee069d443ff16e9e)

I did it one year ago and forgot to post the answer here :)

You can find the code with the solution [here](https://github.com/root-project/root/blob/master/graf2d/fitsio/src/TFITS.cxx#L527).

I actually used the scheme you proposed @CraigM, i.e. combining `fits_read_descript` and `fits_read_col`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, probably you might have seen this/thought about this, but just in case if you havent.

fits_get_col_display_width() = to know the number of characters available

If fits_read_descript() gives the number of elements in the array and starting offset, can the total number of bytes be read into a string and tokenize with delimiter "," and get the numbers?

Comment: Hi @lorenz, thanks for your help.
`fits_get_col_display_width()` crashes when used on a variable-length column.
But you are right `fits_read_descript(fitsfile *fptr, int colnum, LONGLONG rownum, > long *repeat, long *offset, int *status)` returns the number of elements `repeat` and the starting `offset`. Just I do not know how to employ them... there is a `fits_read_tblbytes(fitsfile *fptr, LONGLONG firstrow, LONGLONG firstchar, LONGLONG nchars, > unsigned char *values, int *status)` but the documentation is not clear on what `firstrow`, `firstchar` and `nchars` are.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of odd special cases in FITS, and you have found one of them.

I have successfully used this.

1. Call `fits_read_descript{s}{ll}()` to determine the repeat and offset for the row in question.  You can also use the `descripts` variant to determine the repeat and offset for many rows at one time.
2. Call `fits_read_col{null}()` to read the data, one row at a time.  The number of elements is the repeat count you found from step 1, or less if you want a subset.  Set the column, row number and first element as you would normally do.  Using the `null` variant works just fine.

The important thing is you can only read variable length data this way one row at a time, but it saves you the trouble of doing all the byte decoding and heap indexing.  Even if you use the `fits_read_descripts()` variant to determine multiple repeat counts in one function call, you still must call fits_read_col() once for each table row you are interested in.

Reading variable length strings or bit arrays are their own fun diversions, but you look like you just want to read X-ray response matrix data (floating point) so this should answer your question.